# что не так в моем коде?

Tags: golang

Вам нужно написать функцию oneOrTwo(),  которая принимает два целых числа и строку. Строка может иметь значения one, two или любой другой текст.

Возвращать из функции вам нужно два значения. Если строка равна one, нужно вернуть первое число и саму строку. Если строка равна two, нужно вернуть второе число и саму строку. Если строка другая - нужно вернуть 0 и саму строку.

```
func myStr(num1 int, num2 int, str string) (int, string)  { 
    
// if str == "one" {
//      return num1, str
//  } else if str == "two" {
//      return num2, str
//  } else {
//      return 0, str
//  }   
    
    switch {
    case str == "one" :
        return num1, str
    case str == "two" :
        return num2, str
    default:
        return 0, str
    }       
}

func main() {
    res1,res2 := myStr(2, 5, "one")
    fmt.Println(res1, res2)
```

Comment: выдает ошибку:  undefined: oneOrTwo

Comment: «Вам нужно написать функцию oneOrTwo» — а где в вашем коде функция oneOrTwo?

Comment: _Вам нужно написать функцию oneOrTwo(),_ -- "не нам, а вам"(с) Фактически код у вас рабочий, осталось правильно назвать функцию.

Comment: Вообщем переименуйте функцию `myStr` в `oneOrTwo`, должно заработать.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы ваш код приняла проверочная система, переименуйте функцию `myStr` в `oneOrTwo`.

---

И ещё замечание по коду:

Вашу конструкцию `switch-case` можно упростить так (**можно**, но не обязательно, это просто замечание):

```go
switch str {
case "one":
    return num1, str
case "two":
    return num2, str
default:
    return 0, str
}
```